# An inverter gate reduces the peak-to-peak of the signal!

Tags: not-gate

Using a HCF4049 to invert a signal, I simply fed the input to one of its not-gates and got its output. Here is the result:

[image: Oscilloscope screen shot]

The highlighted red lines is the output of the not-gate. (Yep! my analogue oscilloscope can display colors, it knows how to use my laptop ;D )

The output signal has a smaller peak-to-peak value! Both channels are set to 2 volt/div. So the output's peak-to-peak voltage is about 0.4 to 0.6 volts less than the input. Why?

I switched the probes and also the channels to check if there is any problem with the oscilloscope calibration. But got the same result.

If it is important, [here](http://www.zimmers.net/anonftp/pub/cbm/documents/projects/interfaces/soundcard2tape.html) is the original circuit (the link to schematics is in the middle of the page.)

This is my modified version. I have added A4, and the CH1 and CH2 are where the probes are.

[image: My modified circuit]

To check the oscilloscope accuracy, here the CH1 is connected to 5V and the CH2 is the output as before:

[image: VCC on oscilloscope]

Comment: What's connected to the output of A4 (READ)? If (a decent amount of) current is sunk, than that's the explanation. If not, note the datasheet (Electrical characteristics) only defines the minimum output \$V_{OH}\$, no typical value. So, deviations on typical values may be the explanation. Try the 2 other NOT gates and check if you see the same behaviour.

Comment: Try adding a 0.1 uF capacitor from Vcc to ground.

Comment: After adding this 100nF as close as possible to the power pins of the HCF4049 IC, do measure the 5V supply of the IC as well. If you're still measuring 4.4Vpp (blue scope line: 2.2div) it is likely your 5V is no 5.0V either.

Comment: Tried adding a 100nF capacitor, but didn't change the results. The IC supply is 4.99 to 5.01 volts.

Comment: R5 draws current; that current * rout of the circuit, is a voltage drop.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf And therefore the **output** of NOT gate A4 is lower than the input to which the R5 is connected?

Comment: @Sohail Could you short the input of gate A1 to ground and measure the input and output of gate A4 **with a multimeter**? And next, short the input of gate A1 to the 5V and measure the input and output of gate A4? Please share your findings.

Comment: @Huisman Here is the result:
A1 input to GND: A4 in: 0.005v, A4 out: 4.99v - 
A1 input to VCC: A4 in: 4.91v, A4 out: 0.068v

Comment: A 741 op amp powered with +5V only? Unbelievable! That schematic appears to have multiple errors. What is the actual op amp part number? Can you show us the waveform at its output?

Comment: @Sohail The LEDs wont light up when they are conneted as shown in the schematics above. Did you swap them to the correct polarity and do you see LED2 burning sometimes? Did you add a resistor in series with LED2? If your answers are resp. yes, yes and no, then driving LED2 is likely the cause of the problem.

Comment: @Huisman Great! You are right! the LEDs didn't light up when I first assembled the circuit on bread-board. I simply thought it was my mistake and swapped them to match the GND and VCC, and they work. I didn't guess that maybe the schematic were wrong! I didn't add a resistor, and none of the LEDs have been burnt out yet.

Comment: @Huisman You are right. The LEDs didn't light up when I first assembled the circuit on bread-board. I simply thought it was my mistake and swapped them to match the GND and VCC, and they work. I didn't guess that maybe the schematic were wrong! I didn't add a resistor, and none of the LEDs have been burnt out yet. I also took out the LEDs, but no change in the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there's a tiny difference, but the point is, it's a difference that doesn't (or at least, shouldn't) matter in any way to whatever is receiving the signal. That's the whole point of digital signals — only two states matter, and as long as you can cleanly distinguish the two states, you're good to go.

Comment: I think OP’s question is why does it deviate from the datasheet’s specs.

Comment: @BlairFonville: But the point is, it doesn't! The datasheet only specifies a minimum level for \$V_{OH}\$ and a maximum level for \$V_{OL}\$, which are clearly being met. (Curiously, the [TI datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4050b.pdf) doesn't specify the load current for these values.)

Comment: But doesn’t the minimum level (4.95) say that the output should be that, or higher?  Ex. this shows min. 4.95 V and typically 5 V. http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4050b.pdf

Comment: @DaveTweed Blue line peak-to-peak is 2.2div, so 4.4V. So, I wonder if the level for \$V_{OH}\$ is *clearly* met.

Comment: @Huisman: Are you certain that the OP's power supply and scope are calibrated that accurately? I'm just looking at the *relative* amplitude of the two signals.

Comment: @DaveTweed No. I'm not. But would neither draw the conclusion (yet) the datasheet is met.

Comment: @Huisman: There are just too many unknowns about the OP's setup and methodology. The likelihood that the chip is NOT meeting its specifications is WAY down on the list of probabilities.

Comment: @Huisman I am not sure how calibrated my devices are. Just added another image of the oscilloscope showing the 5v input. It looks the same as what my multi-meter says.

Comment: @DaveTweed You answered BlairFonville: "The datasheet only specifies... clearly being met". I fail to see the specs are met. I just wondered: Based on what did you conclude the specs were clearly met?

Comment: @Huisman: My apologies; you're right. I didn't have enough information to make that assertion at the time. I withdraw the comment.