# Schmitt trigger using CMOS inverters

Tags: digital-logic, cmos, schmitt-trigger

How does this circuit exactly work?

[image]

Source: Problem 8.14, Introduction To Digital Microelectronic Circuits by K. Gopal Gopalan

Comment: Here you can find the explanation https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/430912/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-resistor-in-parallel-with-a-buffer-gate/431076#431076

Comment: Exactly what I am looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It works as a latch to hold the last state of Vi. Those 2 invertors act as a buffer (high-Z input low-Z output). Rf provides the feedback back into the input of the current state. Ri provides isolation from the feedback network but overrides the feedback with a lower (dominant) resistance (condition: Ri << Rf).